# Should not allow angle brackets from regex

Tags: html, angularjs, regex

The below code is not allowing to enter the angle brackets which is good, but it is also not allowing to remove last character from the input box. I should able to make it empty.

```
ng-pattern-restrict="[^<>]+"
```

Comment: In the future, please edit the closed question rather than creating yet another one.

Comment: Isn't ```+``` the problem? Is using ```*``` instead, working?

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code examples should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is right code angle brackets from regex `^((?![<>]).)*$`